# Scrapy - unexpected suffix "%0A" in links

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping a site to download email addresses from websites. 
I have a simple Scrapy crawler, which takes a .txt file with domains and then scrape them to find email addresses.

Unfortunately Scrapy is adding suffix "%0A" in links. You can see it on log file.

Here is my code:

```
class EmailsearcherSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'emailsearcher'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []
    unique_data = set()

    def __init__(self):
        for line in open('/home/*****/domains',
                     'r').readlines():
            self.allowed_domains.append(line)
            self.start_urls.append('http://{}'.format(line))


    def parse(self, response):
        emails = response.xpath('//body').re('([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)')
        for email in emails:
            print(email)
            print('\n')
            if email and (email not in self.unique_data):
                self.unique_data.add(email)
                yield {'emails': email}
```

domains.txt:

```
link4.pl/kontakt
danone.pl/Kontakt
axadirect.pl/kontakt/dane-axa-direct.html
andrzejtucholski.pl/kontakt
premier.gov.pl/kontakt.html
```

Here are logs from console:

```
2017-09-26 22:27:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-09-26 22:27:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-09-26 22:27:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6026
2017-09-26 22:27:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.premier.gov.pl/kontakt.html> from <GET http://premier.gov.pl/kontakt.html>
2017-09-26 22:27:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://andrzejtucholski.pl/kontakt> from <GET http://andrzejtucholski.pl/kontakt%0A>
2017-09-26 22:27:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://axadirect.pl/kontakt/dane-axa-direct.html%0A> from <GET http://axadirect.pl/kontakt/dane-axa-direct.html%0A>
2017-09-26 22:27:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.link4.pl/kontakt> from <GET http://link4.pl/kontakt%0A>
2017-09-26 22:27:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://danone.pl/Kontakt%0a> from <GET http://danone.pl/Kontakt%0A>
```

Comment: Don't use `readlines()`; a file is already an iterator, which lets you read one line at a time from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right solution. I had to use **rstrip** function.

```
 self.start_urls.append('http://{}'.format(line.rstrip()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%0A` is the newline character. Reading the lines keeps the newline characters intact. To get rid of them, you may use [string.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) function, like this:

```
            self.start_urls.append('http://{}'.format(string.strip(line)))
```

Comment: I found out that, .rstrip function is better here. Anyway, thank your for your answer!